# How to remote debug an EAR using Intelij?

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, intellij-idea, ear

I have a `maven java` project that creates an `EAR` file that I then deploy on `Jboss EAP`.

The front end is `AngularJS`, I would like to be able to run the front end locally and connect to the back end code using breakpoints, etc in `IntelliJ`.

**I cannot see any guides on how to do this online, how can I do so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the remote debug option for connecting to your backend. Check the official documentation to learn how to do this:

- [Run/Debug Configuration: Remote Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html)
- [Tutorial: Remote debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html)